# Tomcat doesn't see Windows files

Tags: dual-boot, tomcat

I've a dual boot machine.

I've written a Java method to execute java.io.File.list(pathname)

When I run the method from a terminal window, supplying the pathname over stdio, I can see the Windows XP files from ubuntu.  But when I use a htm interface, via Apache Tomcat, the response is that /media/ is empty.

Is the problem something to do with the access rights of the service running Tomcat? Or a Tomcat configuration issue?

-- -- Additional info added 23 Jan

Using ps, I see that the UID of the process running tomcat is tomcat7

Output from ls -l /media/george is

drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16384 Jan 22 12:20 xp

Comment: who owns `/media/youruser/your_windows_device`?

Comment: it could be a file permission issue. try ```ps -ef | grep tomcat``` to check which user is running tomcat and whether or not it has the permission to the windows files.

Comment: The permissions for "other" on /media/george/xp are rwx, so why can't the tomcat7 process  see /media/george/xp ?